# Connecting password-protected Excel to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to link a password-protected Excel document to Access - this is not working due to the it being password-protected.

Does anyone have an alternative method to do this?

It has to be password-protected unfortunately and cannot be moved to a secured folder so not sure how to do it.

Any advice?

Comment: How it does not work, do you have any error message ?

Comment: I get an error "external table is not in the expected format" - However if I take the password off the excel document it works fine

Comment: Are you opening the Excel doc before trying to access it?

Comment: No - We are looking to automate everything so don't want to open multiple things to get the final result we are after

Comment: I think that is the issue, you must open it with password, then can execute what you want. You can open it hidden if you don't want users to see it.

Comment: You don't want to include the password in the linking mechanism?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a hidden form to automatically open the Excel file when the database file is opened.

Add this to a new Module:

```
Option Compare Database
Public xl As Object

Function OpenExcelFile()
    xl.Workbooks.Open "path to file.xlsx", , , , "password"
End Function

Function CloseExcelFile()
    xl.Quit
    set xl=nothing
End Function
```

Create a blank form and set the HasModule property to true.  then add the following to the form's code module.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    OpenExcelFile
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
    CloseExcelFile
End Sub
```

Now create a new macro with an OpenForm task to open your form.  Set the window mode to 'Hidden'.  Save the macro with the name 'AutoExec'.  This makes it run when the db is opened.

When the db is opened the macro will run and open the form hidden.  The form load event will fire, creating a public Excel.Application object that opens your excel file (you should be able to remove the password from the code if you want the user to be prompted for it).  The Excel application will remain open until the hidden form closes (when you close the database).  At that point the form close event will fire, causing the Excel Application to quit.  As long as the Excel file is open, you should be able to use linked tables and queries.

**You could add xl.Visible=true to the OpenExcelFile function if you want it to be visible to the user.

This link as a similar idea: https://www.connectionstrings.com/how-to-open-password-protected-excel-workbook/